# Question About Semi-interquartile Range

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation

So I have a homework question that I'm stuck on. 
Part A asks: Explain why you cannot calculate the semi-interquartile range if you know only the difference between either Q3 and the median or the median and Q1. I was able to answer this question, but I got stuck on the next question. 
Part B asks: Explain how you would determine the semi-interquartile range if you did know both of the differences in part a. Now, I thought the answer would be to subtracting Q3 from Q1 and dividing it by 2. But the answer key says that you add the differences and then divide it by 2. I'm lost as to why it says to add them. Clearly I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Comment: Hint: Remember that $SIQR = \frac{Q_3 - Q_1}{2}$. You are given $a = Q_3 - Q_2$ and $b=Q_2 - Q_1$. What do you get when you look at $a+b$?

Comment: @knrumsey I got it. I can’t believe I couldn’t figure this one out. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: As this has now been answered, another answer is that knowing one difference is enough if it is also known that the quartiles are symmetrically distributed about the median, but this is nowhere stated or implied. Further, it is easy to imagine two differences that are not equal numerically, so any such counter-example underlines the point.

Comment: The three quartiles of an exponential distribution with rate=1 (hence mean = 1) are not evenly spaced, so the two differences you mention are not always equal.  In R, 
 `qexp(c(.25,.5,.75),1)` returns $Q_1 = 0.2877, Med = 0.6931, Q_3 = 1.3863.$ Sample quartiles from a large sample take similar values; `quantile(rexp(10^5,1))` returns respective sample quantiles:  0.2835, 0.6890, 1.3823 for one such sample of 10,000.

Comment: @  BruceET Thank you so much for responding to my post. Can you please dumb this down for me just so I understand it better? Thank you.